# Automapping Collections

Tags: c#, .net, collections, automapper

I am using [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for mapping my domain model and DTO.
When I map `Mapper.Map<SiteDTO, SiteEntity>` **it works fine**.

> **But when I use collections of the same entities, it doesn't map.**

```
 Mapper.Map<Collection<SiteEntity>, Collection<SiteDTO>>(siteEntityCollection);
```

AS per Automapper [Wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays), it says the lists implementing `ICollection` would be mapped, I am using Collection that implements ICollection, but automapper doesn't map it. Am I doing something wrong.

```
public class SiteEntity //SiteDTO has exactly the same properties, so I am not posting it here.
    {
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate{ get; set; }
        public long TimeStamp{ get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public string Notes{ get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<AreaEntity> Areas{ get; set; }
        public void SiteEntity()
         {
           Areas=new ObservableCollection<AreaEntity>();
         }
     }
```

**EDIT:** SiteEntity updated to include the constructor.

Comment: Do you have mappings for inner collections set in your mapper? do you have mapping for AreaEntity to AreEntityDto set?

Comment: @EIYusubov Thanks for answering, but I am not able to resolved the issue. I would post the entities and code I am using for mapping later today. Maybe if possible, you can have a look and suggest what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `IList<>` without any problems.
I would check the mapping of child domain models first. 
Most probably they are not set yet. In your example: mapping of AreaEntity -> AreaEntityDto.

```
Mapper.Map<AreaEntity, AreaEntityDto>
```

Code example from wiki:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentSource, ParentDestination>()
    .Include<ChildSource, ChildDestination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ChildSource, ChildDestination>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted Automapper will fail to map because you do not have a default constructor for SiteEntity that creates a new ObservableCollection Areas.

Since this is not there you will get a null reference exception when it trys to map Areas.

Comment: In original code, I have the constructor to instantiate the ObservableCollection Areas. I just didn't post it here to make the question concise. Please see the updated SiteEntity.